# Java how to read a certain Number and display it as a figure

Tags: java

RightTriangle.java: Write code that reads in a number R from the user, and displays a figure with R rows of "$" characters as the following pattern. For instance, if the user enters a 4 for R, your program should display:

```
$$$$ 
$$$
$$  
$
```

Heres my code currently.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class RightTriangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int R;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");

        R = sc.nextInt($);

        System.out.println(R);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: two nested loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this task like so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class triangle{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int R;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
    R = sc.nextInt();
    int k = R;
    for(int i=0; i<R; i++){
      for(int j=k; j>0; j--){
        System.out.print('$');
      }
      k = k - 1;
      System.out.print('\n');
    }
  }
}
```

We use two for loops. The first `for loop` is used to print a newline after the nested `for loop` printed the correct amount of `$` for that line. Note how we decrease the value of the inner loop counter inside the outer `for loop` to decrease the amount of `$` printed each line.

Comment: So, I was basically just missing the for loop then. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a descending for-loop with the input as the index.

In each iteration, print the $ symbol i times. You could do this using a loop or using another way.

EDIT:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RightTriangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int R;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");

        R = sc.nextInt(10);
        for (int i = R; i >0; i--) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                sb.append("$");
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

A little late, but here it is anyway :)

Comment: This the only way I thought to achieve the solution. If you can, improve the answer adding some code. :)